# Not able to connect to bluetooth devices in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, ideapad

I am not able to connect any bluetooth devices to my lenovo ideapad running Ubuntu 22.04. iam able to turn bluetooth on. But my laptop is not visible to any other devices and other devices are not detected on my laptop either.
running
`sudo systemctl status bluetooth`
gives

````
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-03-12 02:22:46 GMT; 31s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 9564 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8452)
     Memory: 808.0K
        CPU: 37ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─9564 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd```
````

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'`